# Array populate outside function - non accessable members

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a simple page here to demonstrate the issue that I am seeing.

I am defining a multidimensional array, populating it outside my functions. When I use ajax to send back some data to pupulate the array with the code seems to be adding the data to a temporary array.

When I try to access the array in my function once all ajax has been returned, I am only able to access the last row populate. All other rows return empty strings.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=result>
</div>
<textarea id="the_code"></textarea>
    <script language=javascript>
                var images = [[0,"/upload/cut/1339722764_0_0.png", ""],[1,"/upload/cut/1339722764_0_1.png", ""]];                   

                var numOfImages=1;
                var recievedImages=0;
                var num_row=1;
                var num_col=2;
                var x=0;

                function recieveCode(codeid,emcode)
                {       
                    recievedImages=recievedImages+1;
                    images[codeid][2]=emcode;
                    $('#result').html('Generating: ' + Math.round(((recievedImages/numOfImages) * 100)) + '%');   

                    if (recievedImages == numOfImages)
                    {                   
                        var i = 0;
                        var j = 0;
                        var imageID = "";
                        for(i = 0; i < num_row ; i++)
                        {
                            for(j = 0; j < num_col; j++)
                            {
                                if (j < num_col - 1)
                                {                                   
                                    imageID = imageID + "[[" + images[ (i*num_col) + j][2] + "]] "; 
                                }
                                else
                                {                                       
                                    imageID = imageID + "[[" + images[(i*num_col) + j][2] + "]]\n";
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        $('#the_code').val(imageID);
                    }
                }   
                for (x=0;x<numOfImages;x++)
                {
                    $.ajax(
                    {   
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {album : '223427061111247',image: images[x][1],auth: 'AAAB0ghwtqi0BAFI6xrLYurkQZBT2KWaiKUL3Jxbof3B5xdCIjZBpoImF0Q2ZAaqBC9ofzSPhGoCejyVaYNwIjC44Bay8gIR9Nj38KtGIxyhhgybbIOI' },
                        url: 'upload_emoticode.php',
                        success:function(msg){   recieveCode(images[x][0],msg); }
                    }
                    );
                }                                   
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to ajax is asynchronous so by the time `recieveCode` is called, `x` is always equal to `numOfImages`. You can fix this by wrapping the call to ajax in an a self calling function that encapsulates each image in a closure like this:

```
for (x=0;x<numOfImages;x++)
{
    (function(image){
        $.ajax(
        {   
            type: "POST",
            data: {album : '223427061111247',image: image[1],auth: 'AAAB0ghwtqi0BAFI6xrLYurkQZBT2KWaiKUL3Jxbof3B5xdCIjZBpoImF0Q2ZAaqBC9ofzSPhGoCejyVaYNwIjC44Bay8gIR9Nj38KtGIxyhhgybbIOI' },
            url: 'upload_emoticode.php',
            success:function(msg){   recieveCode(image[0],msg); }
        }
        );
    })(images[x]);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly. I would never have figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your *x* is in the wrong scope due to the asynchronous nature of these Ajax calls.  Try creating a closure like this:

```
(function(currentX) {
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        data: {album : '223427061111247',image: images[currentX][1],auth: 'AAAB0ghwtqi0BAFI6xrLYurkQZBT2KWaiKUL3Jxbof3B5xdCIjZBpoImF0Q2ZAaqBC9ofzSPhGoCejyVaYNwIjC44Bay8gIR9Nj38KtGIxyhhgybbIOI' },
        url: 'upload_emoticode.php',
        success:function(msg){   recieveCode(images[currentX][0],msg); }
    });
)(x);
```

Think of it like this.  When you make your Ajax call, the loop keeps running while it waits for the server to respond.  By the time the *success* callback has been invoked, the *i* variable has already been incremented several more times.  The modified code above creates a copy of *i* for each iteration of the loop.